# Browser image cache and jQuery.load() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code example:

```
var img = $("img");
var n = img.length;
var i = 0;
function loadImg(i) {
    if( i < n ) {
        $(img[i]).load( function() {
            console.log("img["+i+"] loaded");
            i++;
            loadImg(i);
        });
    } else {
        console.log("img["+i+"] loaded");
        return false;
    }
}
loadImg(0);
```

This code works, but when image already in a browser cache - jQuery.load is not firing.
How can I check to see if the picture is in a browser cache and forcibly fire jQuery.load?

Thanks.

Comment: don't forget to select your answer once you found one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul Irish has written a neat little plugin for that. It does exactly what you want, including images loaded from cache:

https://github.com/paulirish/jquery.imgloaded

I've updated your fiddle with the above plugin included. This should answer your question:

http://jsbin.com/acuhaf/9/edit

Comment: Nice idea, dut in my example doesn't work in IE8. FF, Chrome, IE9+ ok.

Comment: Note that this script should be used in the footer. Did you try that? Do you maybe have a fiddle where we can work in together to solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks Robin. I'll create a fiddle. mb jsbin.com? Or what you can advice?

Comment: You can open this fiddle in IE9 or IE10 and you will see the problem in console. To see "full loaded" message in console, we need to refresh browser 3-4 times...

Comment: You're not using the above plugin in your fiddle, why is that? I thought we were trying to solve your issue using the plugin I suggested. Edit: I've added the plugin myself. See answer.

Comment: I saw... But it not helps... IE8 on first load page fires callback function only 4 times.

Comment: Are you even reading what I'm saying here? It's *not* about *your* code example which fires an event for every image that is loaded. It's about the plugin here which fires *one* event when *all* the images are loaded. *Read my code example*

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) says:

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>   A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load() shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. 
>   
>   
> There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. 
>   
> These are:
>   
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
>   
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
>   
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
>   
> - **Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache**

You may want to use other library to preload images. I would recommend [PreloadJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS)